# como pegar o valor do option que foi escolhido?

Tags: javascript, combobox

sou inciante em programação e gostaria de saber como que faz pra pegar o valor do option selecionado e colocar em uma variavel?
por exemplo, o usuário escolhe 'Antigas'. e eu salvo a escolha dele em uma variável

```
<select id="cmbTempo" name="cmbTempo">
    <option>Selecione:</option>
    <option value="old" >Antigas</option>
    <option value="new">Atuais</option>
    <input type="submit" name="btnOK">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma ideia seria usar o onchange para definir a variável assim que o usuário mexer no select

```js
var select   = document.getElementById("cmbTempo");
var variavel = '';
select.onchange = function(){
    variavel = this.value;
    console.log(variavel);
}
```

```html
<select id="cmbTempo" name="cmbTempo">
    <option>Selecione:</option>
    <option value="old" >Antigas</option>
    <option value="new" selected="selected">Atuais</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine que você tem um select:

```
<select id="cmbTempo" name="cmbTempo">
    <option>Selecione:</option>
    <option value="old" >Antigas</option>
    <option value="new" selected="selected">Atuais</option>
    <input type="submit" name="btnOK">
</select>
```

Para pegar o valor númerico da opção desejada faça:

```
var element = document.getElementById("cmbTempo");
var valorSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

Isso vai colocar 'new' em **valorSel**. Se você quer pegar o texto 'Atuais':

```
var element = document.getElementById("cmbTempo");
var textoSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
```

o que vai colocar 'Atuais' na variável **textoSel**.

Answer (score 0):

Como voce quer capturar o valor faça o seu codigo desse modo esta funcionado perfeitamente. Atrele o adicionar o valor do select no click do seu botao ( tira o input submit) e use o codigo assim:

HTML:

```
<select id="cmbTempo" name="cmbTempo">
    <option>Selecione:</option>
    <option value="old" >Antigas</option>
    <option value="new" selected="selected">Atuais</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="btnOK" id="botao">gravar</button>
```

Agora vem o javascript:

```
<script>

    var botao = document.getElementById('botao');
    botao.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var select = document.getElementById('cmbTempo').value;
        console.log(select);
    })
```

Prontinho, sempre que clicar no botao sera inserido um valor na variavel "select"