# Queria saber como declarar que a option foi selecionada no Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

```
<select name="fontes" id="fontes-lista">
                <option value="fonte1" id="fontes-lista1">nome</option>
                <option value="fonte2" id="fontes-lista2">Nome</option>
                <option value="fonte3" id="fontes-lista3">Nome</option>
                <option value="fonte4" id="fontes-lista4">Nome</option>
                <option value="fonte5" id="fontes-lista5">Nome</option>
                <option value="fonte6" id="fontes-lista6">Nome</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [como pegar o valor do option que foi escolhido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/385708/como-pegar-o-valor-do-option-que-foi-escolhido)

Answer (score 0):

Veja se o exemplo abaixo resolve:

```
<select id="frutas">
    <option value="fruta01">Maçã</option>
    <option value="fruta02">Laranja</option>
    <option value="fruta03">Banana</option>
    <option value="fruta04">Uva</option>
</select>


<script>
    const selectElement = document.getElementById("frutas");
   

    selectElement.addEventListener("change", function() {
        const opcaoSelecionada = selectElement.value;
        console.log("Você selecionou a fruta: " + opcaoSelecionada );
    });
</script>
```